# Groovy Mixin persistent properties with JPA

Tags: jpa, groovy, mixins

I would like to define a JPA persisted property in a Groovy Mixin and then use it in several entity classes. I couldn't get this to work with JPA annotations and Hibernate - has anyone been successful with this combination?

I have a set up an example Maven project which shows what I'm trying to do and a single JUnit test which defines the behavior I would like.

https://github.com/gilday/groovy-mixin-jpa-test

Briefly:

```
@Category(Person) class HasPreferences {

    @ElementCollection
    final Collection<Preference> preferences = []
}

@Entity
@Mixin(HasPreferences)
class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id

    String name
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `@Mixin` is dynamic, i doubt JPA will be able to find your mixed properties. I think you need some compile-time code generation, like `@Delegate`. Even so, JPA will try to persist the generated property. There is a [discussion in groovy mailing](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Some-Mixin-woes-td5712770.html) list concerning the creation of a `@Trait` annotation which might be what you want.

Comment: I've had mixed success with `@Trait`. My suggestion would be to avoid them.